# How to match the right type for an array of Unions using Array.prototype.find?

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```js
type A = { style: 'A', x: string }
type B = { style: 'B', y: string }

type Union = A | B;
```

I'm trying to find the element of type `A` in a `Union[]`, like this:

```
const data: Union[] = [
    { style: 'A', x: 'test' },
    { style: 'B', y: 'test' },
]

const a: A | undefined = data.find(d => d.style === 'A');
```

But that throws the error:

```
Type 'A | B | undefined' is not assignable to type 'A | undefined'.
  Property 'x' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.
```

The predicate function for `Array.prototype.find` has no problems finding the right type, I can access the properties of `A` without any issues:

[image: type A props]

Is the return type that misses the refinement.

---

The only way I've been able to work around it is with a for loop, but that feels cumbersome and unnecessary.

```
let a: A | undefined;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    const val = data[i];
    if (val.style === 'A') { 
        a = val;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate `d => d.style === 'A'` is inferred as type `(d: Union) => boolean`.

For your desired behaviour, it would have to be inferred as `(d: Union) => d is A`, i.e. a [user-defined type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). This won't happen because Typescript never infers that a function is a user-defined type guard; if you want it to be, you have to explicitly declare it as one. If you write it like this, then it works:

```js
function isA(d: Union): d is A {
    return d.style === 'A';
}

const a: A | undefined = data.find(isA); // no error
```

Actually, when I started writing this answer I going to say that this is probably impossible, because it would require `Array.prototype.find`'s return type to depend on whether or not the predicate is a user-defined type guard. I didn't think that was possible, but [apparently it is](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L11); I only discovered it works by testing it, so I learned something today, too.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDOoA2EBcUDkMeANFAB67oBOAlgHYDmUAvgFCiRQBCCyamO+TsSggKwGg2Ys24aAFVa1APa0ecAD5cA3NIDGK9FAAmAQ2AncC5bQDaAXR42WUF73QgsuAsPL5gEdDxmImdXFHdPQWFRPwDgIKYQu2kAMwBXWl1gayhqVBgACiNLRRUASlwjXNRYZFCXSghgNMpVIwA6COh4HvxCHVYWfVpDC1rNDKMIFLoIKsRTc3aZ2iMCvJgynWkgA)

Comment: But that's not very safe since I can do:

`function isA(d: Union): d is A {
    return d.style === 'B';
}`

And the compiler won't catch the error.

Comment: Yes, Typescript allows you to write unsound user-defined type guards. It's your responsibility to write the type guard function correctly. Treat them like type assertions - you are telling the compiler that you know something has a stricter type than what the compiler is able to infer, so you are overruling the compiler's judgement, and you should do so carefully. In practice, type guard functions are usually short and easy to verify manually, so they are safer than type assertions most of the time.

Comment: IMO, using unsound guards defeats the purpose of typescript. Of course, it will be safe to use that guard at first, but if the underlying definition of the type changes, we would be introducing a runtime error that should've been prevented by the type we're now coercing. It may not be a problem for small projects, but it is for a large codebase, with many contributors.

Comment: The type guard in my answer isn't unsound; it does correctly check whether a `Union` is an `A`. If you're worried about it falling out of sync with the definition of `A`, I would suggest writing the type guard function right next to `A`'s definition so that that's more likely. Your two options here are either to write the code in a way which Typescript can check, or to write a minimal amount of code that Typescript doesn't check; if you don't want the latter, then you cannot use `Array.prototype.find` for this purpose so your only other option is the one you rejected in the question.

Comment: @davidmh user-defined type guards are intentionally unsound; TypeScript is, in places, intentionally unsound, for better or worse.  It is specifically a [non-goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) to apply a sound type system, especially when soundness blocks productivity.  User-defined type guards are so useful that it actually hurts to avoid them entirely just because they *can* be misused.  What if you wrote a generic "discriminated union checker" type guard somewhere and used that?  Would that be more palatable?  Here, let me write it up:

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDOoA2EBcUDkMeANFAB67oBOAlgHYDmUAvgFCiRQBCCyamO+TsSggKwGg2YsobcNACqtagHtaPOAB8uAbhYsAxqvRQAJgENgZ3IpW0A2gF0ed6b3QgsuAsPL5gEdDxmIlcUd09BYVE-AOAgphCHPUNaYxNqVH0aAFs6CwgTG1UAcQBXM0oTBFcAHgBpKAhSf1oTVCgABUplSEpQOogQEgA1RuaIVvaqOkYtWlLsgCMISigtReVlLDNaAD4AClcoKABrQdw6kgA3MwxcYdcASgRdqBqAFTGWtqgAJQhDJV6iMvhMfu87HUnAB+KClWgnWjKADuanuuwORygykWACtcO8nrgcbioBkoABRZqUMz6YAfEj-QEmYFQYYYl5Y44kuxnEBOeCCqA3DC6AxGYBQMw8cyWAB0ADM6CZ9ulMjk8v5CkoSuVKvsAEThCAGkgGmAGx6PbRQAD0ttgazhrQgStoBSAA).

Comment: That type indeed makes it more palatable, thank you jcalz, would you mind updating kaya3's answer with your example?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `Array.prototype.find` is:

```
find<S extends T>(predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined;
```

Pay attention to the `predicate` callback return type: `value is S`. This passed-in predicate is already intended to narrow down your result. So no need to define an extra funtion, you can write it inline:

```
const a: A | undefined = data.find((d): d is A => d.style === 'A'); // works
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=68&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDOoA2EBcUDkMeANFAB67oBOAlgHYDmUAvgFCiRQBCCyamO%20TsSggKwGg2Ys24aAFVa1APa0ecAD5cA3NIDGK9FAAmAQ2AncC5bQDaAXR42WUF73QgsuAsPL5gEdDxmImdXFHdPQWFRPwDgIKYQuz0DYCgLWChNAFdaIwgAMzoIIx5TcwA6IryAChqjAEpcUupUTPgAPmMKiOh4fvxCBq0gA)

Comment: Same as @kaya3's in answer: 

`const a: A | undefined = data.find((d): d is A => d.style === 'B'); // works but it shouldn't`